# Javascript sticky menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added a stickytab script to my website http://www.blisshair.com.au
The purpose of the sticktabs is so that the ads (and nav menu) on the left hand side will 'follow' the user.
I have implemented the script somewhat successfully, however, you will notice that if you scroll all the way down on the index page, the ads on the left hand side overlap the footer.

I have attempted to read through the JS, after being unsuccessful I have used another script (jquery stickybox) and the issue is the exact same, so I believe it to be a css issue.

I have attempted to set a margin for the footer and left menu, and at the moment I am unable to see where the error lies.

If anyone is able to help, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Hi Nik, i have just gone through with your problem, acc to me issue is your floating div is able to calculate top:740.8px in jquery code but not bottom, thats why it going to the bottom of the page instead of its parent container id="content-container". Please try to look again in jquery code or calculate the bottom space of its container.

Comment: I have gone through the code but as a very unexperienced JS programmer, I am having difficulties in editing the code. At the moment I am rewriting all the divs and CSS for the page, hopefully this will fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this css it will give output you want but not for all pages i think because the height of the page varies from one page to another. But any way check it out.

i have set the height of id="leftwrapper". 
Here is the code

```
#leftwrapper { width:200px; position:relative; height:825px; float:left; }
```

temporary add `border:1px solid magenta;` to #leftwrapper so you can see the boundaries of the div.

Comment: Hey, thats the same plug in that I am having issues with.
I can get one box to move successfully, But i have 3 divs right underneath one another. I want both divs to move down the side as the user scrolls. Scrolling successfully but once it reaches the bottom the last div overlaps the footer. 
Please see blisshair.com.au for issue. thanks :)